# Access.log with Log4j2 on tomcat as JSON

Tags: java, json, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I have tomcat 8 configured and running nicely with log4j2.
Also catalina spooling nice JSON log with JSONlayout.
But here is a thing.
**Does anyone know how to switch to JSONlayout for Tomcat's access file or even address Tomcat accessfile with log4j2 and it's pattern?**
Tomcat still spooling localhost_access_log in default format.

Answer (score 1):

The Tomcat access log is defined as a valve in server.xml file, there you can set whatever pattern you like, even use another implementation of the valve for access logging.

Take a look to this for more details: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

Regards.